# Random Graph Generation but with weights

Tags: python, graph-theory, weighted-graph

Hey so I'm doing a project where cities will be symbolized by vertices and streets with edges. I found this very cool erdos_renyi_graph function but I need some features that I couldn't find so far:

1. every edge should have their (also random) weight
2. I need to be sure that every vertice have at least 2 edges.

Can I do this with Erdős–Rényi Generator or maybe there is some other function I could use?

I was trying to use "er_np" function to adresse my 1st issue but I believe thats not really what I'm looking for. I was also checking fast_gnp_random_graph() and gnp_random_graph() function but those don't have weights parameters neither.

Comment: 1 Generate the graph with the generator you are currently happy with.  Loop over the edges and assign a random weight

Comment: 2.  Generate the graph with the generator you are currently happy with.  Loop over the vertices and, for each vertex that has just one edge, add an edge connecting it to another, random, vertex.